# How to check if partial/include is called in header?

Tags: php, wordpress

This has been driving me crazy for hours, I feel like it should be so simple but I can't find anything anywhere, I guess I must be using the wrong search terms.

Essentially, I want to call the search form in two places on the same page, it sits in the header bar throughout the site, but also shows on the archive listings above the posts; purely for searching posts (a client request).

I need to check whether it's being called in the header or the content area, so I can change the placeholder text and add in the hidden input so it only searches for posts on the archive page.

I can't seem to find any solution to check if "Not Called In Header" other than creating two forms and calling them separately, which seems like overkill to me.

```
$search_text = 'Search';
$search_posts = false;

if ([Not Called In Header]) {
    if (is_archive() || $_GET['post_type'] == 'post') {
        $search_text = 'Search Articles';
        $search_posts = '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post">';
    }
}

echo '<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="'.home_url( '/' ).'" >';
    echo '<input class="search-input" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="'.$search_text.'" />';
    echo $search_posts;
    echo '<button class="search-submit" type="submit">'.$search_text.'</button>';
echo '</form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution, although it does not depend on the current file/location, would be to make the form output a function within your themes functions.php file (or part of a plugin) then pass in your placeholder text (or other parameters) to the function.

Something like:

```
function my_form_output($search_text){
    $search_posts = false;

    if (is_archive() || $_GET['post_type'] == 'post') {
        $search_posts = '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post">';
    }

    echo '<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="'.home_url( '/' ).'" >';
        echo '<input class="search-input" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="'.$search_text.'" />';
        echo $search_posts;
        echo '<button class="search-submit" type="submit">'.$search_text.'</button>';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

And in the locations you want to use the form use:

```
my_form_output("Search");
```

or

```
my_form_output("Search Articles");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, I tried something similar earlier but my knowledge hit a brick wall. I presume I could do the same for the $search_posts variable?

Comment: Yes, I would be tempted to then pass in a single attribute of "location" (e.g the template name "header" or "single") and then use a case statement to set everything else up. Or you can pass in an array which may be cleaner, something similar to the $args array that WordPress uses in get_posts().

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, very helpful, wish I could upvote more!